# Reformatting a large number of XML files

Tags: find, xargs, xml

I am manipulating a large number of XML files scattered throughout a nested directory structure.

I tried the following:

```
$ find . -name "*.xml" -type f | xargs -- xmllint --format
```

The problem is that generates the formatted XML output on the screen, but doesn't change the file.

How can I change this command so that the actual file contents are changed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be done from `find` directly using `-exec`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f -exec xmllint --output '{}' --format '{}' \;
```

What's passed to `-exec` will be invoked once per file found with the template parameters `{}` being replaced with the current file name.  The `\;` on the end of the find command just terminates the line.

The use of `xargs` isn't really necessary in this case because we need to invoke `xmllint` once per file as both the input and output file names must be specified within the same call.

`xargs` would be needed if the command being piped to from find was working on multiple files at a time and that list was long.  You can't do that in this case, as you need to pass the single filename to the `--output` option of `xmllint`.  Without `xargs` you could end up with a "Argument List too long" error if you are processing a lot of files.  `xargs` also supports file replace strings with the `-I` option:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f | xargs -I'{}' xmllint --output '{}' --format '{}'
```

Would do the same as the `find -exec` command above.  If any of your folders have odd chars in like spaces you will need to use the `-0` options of `find` and `xargs`.  But using `xargs` with `-I` implies the option `-L 1` which means only process 1 file at a time anyway, so you may as well directly use `find` with `-exec`.

Comment: @manatwork thanks for the edits - sticky fingers ;o)

Comment: I just ran this and it appears to work a treat! Many thanks for the prompt and concise response!

Comment: “This will fail if the file list is too large”: No, it won't fail (it's processing a single file at a time), and in fact `find … -exec` is the most direct way to do this.

Comment: @Gilles Good point! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This works due to the fact that `xmllint` firstly loads full xml document into memory and only then parse / write out. This allows document in-place processing.

Comment: @gavenkoa Reference?

Answer (score 9):

I typically attack these problems with a layer of indirection.
Write a shell script that does what you want, and call that.
I'd suggest as a start

```
#! /bin/sh
for file
do
   xmllint --format $file > $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
done
```

The try it out on a file or two by hand, then you can replace it in the xargs

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f | xargs -- xmltidy.sh
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach if I should need to do more complex manipulation in the future. Thanks for the response.